# Viewing Xbox One Network Traffic

Tags: networking, wireshark, xbox-one

I am trying to view the HTTP/HTTPS traffic going from my XBOX one so I can see what is being requested. I started off trying to use Charles proxy like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MP4ZcwSHxbw. However there is no option to use a proxy on xbox one, so I could not use this method.

So next I tried to internet share with my Xbox and Laptop through an ethernet cable.  However the Xbox's requests were not going through Charles proxy for some reason.

So then I tried to use wireshark, with my xbox connected to my PC's internet using an ethernet cable. I can see HTTP requests from my xbox, but cannot see any information about HTTPS not even the URL that is being called.

Does anyone know the best way to see these HTTP and HTTPS requests?

Thanks.

Comment: The entire point of HTTPS requests is so someone doing what you are trying to do can not see what is sent (That includes the URL)

Comment: Well yes, but not if you explicitly trust the computer you want to be able to view the data.  I can see the HTTPS requests from my computer using Charles (http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/), so I know it's possible.  However I can't see these requests from my XBOX one.

Comment: Yes, but you can't tell the XBOX one to explicity trust your computer, you can tell your computer to trust itself or anything you tell it to but you can't tell the xbox that because the OS is locked down (unless you have a mod chip or similar (Do they have mod chips for xbox one yet?))

Comment: Thanks, that helps answer my question.  To make things easier than using WireShark however, do you know how I could get my XBOX to use my proxy?  Either in the settings, or using my PC/Mac's internet via ethernet/internet sharing?  As it would be a lot easier if I could see the HTTP traffic via Charles...